# Problems with SELECTION_CHANGED_ EVENT in Forge Viewer v7*

Tags: treeview, selection, autodesk-viewer, forge, getselection

I have a problem when I upgraded **Forge Viewer** from **v6*** to **v7*** with **SELECTION_CHANGED_ EVENT**, everything is working fine if I select the object from the Viewer, but when I select the object from the Model Browser the getSelection method returns empty.
This works fine in the **v6*** but not in **v7***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model browser behavior has changed in v7. You'll notice that clicking an object in the model browser now *isolates* it instead of *selecting* it. So, for your original use case, consider listening to the `Autodesk.Viewing.ISOLATE_EVENT` event, or to the `Autodesk.Viewing.AGGREGATE_ISOLATION_CHANGED_EVENT` event.

Comment: You got it! :))